# Apply to conditional formatting to all columns, but only compared within each column (Excel)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table of data. Each row applies to one individual and each column is for a single question.

I want to do some really quick analysis of this data by using conditional formatting for every column.

But the question in column B might be "How many apples have you eaten this week?" with a scale of 0 - 10 while the question in column C might be "How many hours a week do you watch TV?" with a scale of 5 - 50. I don't want the colouring (ideally 3 point colouring) to apply over both of these questions the same so that all of column B is red and most of column C is green, simply because they're different ranges.

How do I get the conditional formatting to apply across each column separately?

I have tried going into "Manage rules" and making the condition apply to "=B:B" and then dragging across. This doesn't work. It just reverts it to "=$B:$B" anyway and then makes it "=$B:$AG" after I drag it. Almost like it isn't applying the rules in the way that Excel normally does with a drag.

Data looks like this:

[image: Excel output with multiple ranges across different columns]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding two more rows to specify the `min` and `max` value for each response. Then create three rules with formulas:

```
=(B4-B$2)/(B$3-B$2)>=66%

=(B4-B$2)/(B$3-B$2)>=33%

=(B4-B$2)/(B$3-B$2)<33%
```

The rules should be arranged as in the example.
And apply the rules to the entire range with the response values

[image]